# onPaste not getting triggered for div in sweetalert modal

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, focus, sweetalert2, onpaste

I have a react component where you can paste screenshots from the clipboard. The implementation is like I have a div which is focusable using `tabIndex`. When user focuses on it and paste copied image it is shown in the DOM. The issue is this component works fine in all the places except in the place where it is put inside modal. The package I am using is "sweetalert2-react-content".
Below is the code

```
        <div
          tabIndex={0}
          onPaste={onPaste}
          className="relative h-full border border-dashed border-primary cursor-pointer"
        >
          <div
            className="absolute left-1/2 top-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 flex flex-col items-center"
          >
                <span className="">Paste here or drag and drop the image.</span>
                <p className="text-center">Or</p>
                <label
                  className={`${
                    isNew || isEditable
                      ? 'cursor-pointer bg-[#FFFFFF]'
                      : 'text-[#B1ACA8]'
                  } general-form-input w-fit flex !py-1`}
                >
                  <p
                    className="text-left bg-gray-100 px-4 flex items-center max-w-[200px] "
                    htmlFor={attr[ENTITY_ATTRIBUTES.attributeName]}
                  >
                    <span className="truncate">
                      {typeof value != 'string' && value
                        ? value.name
                        : 'Select a file'}
                    </span>
                  </p>
                  <input
                    id={attr[ENTITY_ATTRIBUTES.attributeName]}
                    type={'file'}
                    accept="image/*"
                    disabled={
                      isDisabled(attr) ||
                      attr[ENTITY_ATTRIBUTES.isReadOnly] == true
                    }
                    className="hidden file-form-input"
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      if (
                        Array.from(e.target.files).every(
                          (file) => file.type.split('/')[0] == 'image'
                        )
                      ) {
                        onFileSelect(e.target.files[0], onChange);
                      }
                    }}
                  />
                  {value instanceof Object ? (
                    <button
                      onClick={(e) => {
                        onChange(null);
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        e.preventDefault();
                      }}
                      className="hover:bg-red-200 hover:text-red-600 h-full px-2 font-extrabold"
                    >
                      <MdClose className="mx-auto " />
                    </button>
                  ) : (
                    <AiOutlineFileAdd className="w-6 h-full" />
                  )}
                </label>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I dug inside the issue and found out that the onPaste event is not getting triggered for the div inside sweetalert modal only. Everywhere else it gets triggered and works fine.